# Newbie trying to scrape data and break it up

Tags: python

I am able to scrape some data from a website but i am having trouble break it up to display it in a table.

The code I use is:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_games.html'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
tablesright = soup.find_all('td', 'right',)
Tables left = soup.find_all('td', 'left')
print (tablesright + tablesleft)
```

This gives me the result like this:

```
====================== RESTART: E:/2017/Python2/box2.py   ======================
[<td class="right " data-stat="game_start_time">8:01 pm</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="visitor_pts">99</td>, <td class="right " data- stat="home_pts">102</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="game_start_time">10:30 pm</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="visitor_pts">122</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="home_pts">121</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="game_start_time">7:30 pm</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="visitor_pts">108</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="home_pts">100</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="game_start_time">8:30 pm</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="visitor_pts">117</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="home_pts">111</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="game_start_time">7:00 pm</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="visitor_pts">90</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="home_pts">102</td>, <
```

and the left part:

```
<td class="left " csk="BOS.201710170CLE" data-stat="visitor_team_name"><a href="/teams/BOS/2018.html">Boston Celtics</a></td>, <td class="left " csk="CLE.201710170CLE" data-stat="home_team_name"><a href="/teams/CLE/2018.html">Cleveland Cavaliers</a></td>, <td class="left " data-stat="game_remarks"></td>, <td class="left " csk="HOU.201710170GSW" data-stat="visitor_team_name"><a href="/teams/HOU/2018.html">Houston Rockets</a></td>, <td class="left " csk="GSW.201710170GSW" data-stat="home_team_name"><a href="/teams/GSW/2018.html">Golden State Warriors</a></td>, <td class="left " data-stat="game_remarks"></td>, <td class="left " csk="MIL.201710180BOS" data-stat="visitor_team_name"><a href="/teams/MIL/2018.html">Milwaukee Bucks</a></td>, <td class="left " csk="BOS.201710180BOS" data-stat="home_team_name"><a href="/teams/BOS/2018.html">Boston Celtics</a></td>, <td class="left " data-stat="game_remarks"></td>, <td class="left " csk="ATL.201710180DAL" data-
```

Ok so now I can not figure out how to break the result up so it would have a nice table like this:

```
Game start time    Home team.     Score.   Away team.    Score
7pm.               Boston.        104.     Golden state.  103
```

Pulling my hair out trying to figure it out,

Ta thanks in advance

Comment: i Guys. Thanks heaps for the help. I understand it and it works for me also. Thankyou.Another quick question, on the website a am scraping. The first field is that date, How come scrape does not pull that back also? The first field it pulls back is the time....Do I need to use different code to get that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try reading that in a pandas dataframe instead of using the html parser and then decide how to manipulate that dataframe into showing the result you need.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_games.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url, match="Start")
print(dfs[0])
```

Examples of how to do that in the pandas documentation as well as a lot of asked questions on stackoverflow. 
Sauce: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you want solution with pandas, this is one without it by just using more advanced `attrs` keyword and standard Python `format` to get formatted table.

Note that numbers in `format` are choosen manually and does not adjust to actual data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_games.html'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
game_start_times = soup.find_all('td', attrs={"data-stat": "game_start_time", "class": "right"})
visitor_team_names = soup.find_all('td', attrs={"data-stat": "visitor_team_name", "class": "left"})
visitor_ptss = soup.find_all('td', attrs={"data-stat": "visitor_pts", "class": "right"})
home_team_names = soup.find_all('td', attrs={"data-stat": "home_team_name", "class": "left"})
home_pts = soup.find_all('td', attrs={"data-stat": "home_pts", "class": "right"})

for i in range(len(game_start_times)):
    print('{:10s} {:28s} {:5s} {:28s} {:5s}'.format(game_start_times[i].text.strip(),
                                  visitor_team_names[i].text.strip(),
                                  visitor_ptss[i].text.strip(),
                                  home_team_names[i].text.strip(),
                                  home_pts[i].text.strip()))
```

---

```
8:01 pm    Boston Celtics               99    Cleveland Cavaliers          102
10:30 pm   Houston Rockets              122   Golden State Warriors        121
7:30 pm    Milwaukee Bucks              108   Boston Celtics               100
8:30 pm    Atlanta Hawks                117   Dallas Mavericks             111
```

Comment: Upvoting for taking the time to format the answer exactly like the OP asked for :D

Answer (score 0):

This would work. Tune it up to your needs and use Panda afterwards.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_games.html'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

rows = soup.select('#schedule > tbody > tr')

for row in rows:
    rights = row.find_all("td", "right")
    lefts = row.find_all("td", "left")

    print rights[0].text, lefts[0].text, rights[1].text, lefts[1].text, rights[2].text
```

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks heaps for the help. I understand it and it works for me also. Thankyou.Another quick question, on the website a am scraping. The first field is that date, How come scrape does not pull that back also? The first field it pulls back is the time....Do I need to use different code to get that?

Comment: The date is a <th>, not a <td>.

You have to scrape it as seen:
`date = row.find_all("th", "left")`
and then:
`print date[0].text`

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple structure, I would just drop the libraries and do it with re (regular expressions)

first one **findall** to get all **tr** tags

then one **findall** to get all **td/th** tags inside each tr tag

then one **sub** to filter out all tags inside the fields (mainly a tags)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.basketball-
reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_games.html'
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.content

data = [
    {
            k:re.sub('<.+?>','',v) for (k,v) in re.findall('<t[dh].+?data\-stat="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</t[dh]',tr)
    } for tr in re.findall('<tr.+?>(.+?)</tr',content)
    ]

for game in data:
  print "%s" % game['date_game']
  for info in game:
    print "  %s = %s" % (info,game[info])
```

This gives a nice dict structure (data) which  can be easily used for displaying as you like :

```
$ ./scores_url.py 
Tue, Oct 17, 2017
  game_remarks = 
  box_score_text = Box Score
  home_team_name = Cleveland Cavaliers
  visitor_team_name = Boston Celtics
  game_start_time = 8:01 pm
  date_game = Tue, Oct 17, 2017
  overtimes = 
  visitor_pts = 99
  home_pts = 102
Tue, Oct 17, 2017
  game_remarks = 
  box_score_text = Box Score
  home_team_name = Golden State Warriors
  visitor_team_name = Houston Rockets
  game_start_time = 10:30 pm
  date_game = Tue, Oct 17, 2017
  overtimes = 
  visitor_pts = 122
  home_pts = 121
Wed, Oct 18, 2017
  game_remarks = 
  box_score_text = Box Score
  home_team_name = Boston Celtics
  visitor_team_name = Milwaukee Bucks
  game_start_time = 7:30 pm
  date_game = Wed, Oct 18, 2017
  overtimes = 
  visitor_pts = 108
  home_pts = 100
...
```

or in the style of your example :

```
cols = [
        ['game_start_time',15,"Game start time"],
        ['home_team_name',25,"Home team."],
        ['home_pts',7,"Score."],
        ['visitor_team_name',25,"Away team."],
        ['visitor_pts',7,"Score."]
       ]

for col in cols:
  print ("%%%ds" % col[1]) % col[2],
print

for game in data:
  for col in cols:
    print ("%%%ds" % col[1]) % game[col[0]],
  print
```

which gives something like this :

```
Game start time                Home team.  Score.                Away team.  Score.
        8:01 pm       Cleveland Cavaliers     102            Boston Celtics      99
       10:30 pm     Golden State Warriors     121           Houston Rockets     122
        7:30 pm            Boston Celtics     100           Milwaukee Bucks     108
        8:30 pm          Dallas Mavericks     111             Atlanta Hawks     117
        7:00 pm           Detroit Pistons     102         Charlotte Hornets      90
        7:00 pm            Indiana Pacers     140             Brooklyn Nets     131
        8:00 pm         Memphis Grizzlies     103      New Orleans Pelicans      91
    ...
```